# Performing multiplication in SQL SERVER(SET BASED APPROACH)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Suppose I have a table like the following:

### tblNumbers

```
Numbers
4  
5
3
6
```

Using SET BASED approach how can I perform a multiplication so the output will be:

```
Output
360
```

N.B~ There is no hard and fast rule that there will be only four numbers, but I'd prefer the answer to be using a CTE and/or correlated subquery.

Comment: try to find if there's an analogous user-defined aggregate in mssql.  this is something(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490875/why-the-result-of-exp-log-of-postgres-differs-from-sql-server) i'm proud with postgresql, it has many features missing in other rdbms :-)

Comment: hmm.. it's possible in mssql users to create user-defined aggregate, but forces the user to use .net http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/02/12/60088.aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use logarithms/exponents that take advantage of the mathematical fact that:

```
log(a*b*c...*n)=log(a)+log(b)+log(c)...+log(n)
```

Therefore you can use the `sum` function to add all the logarithms of a column, then take the exponent of that sum, which gives the aggregate multiplication of that column:

```
create table #tbl (val int)
insert into #tbl (val) values(1)
insert into #tbl (val) values(2)
insert into #tbl (val) values(3)
insert into #tbl (val) values(4)

select exp(sum(log(val))) from #tbl

drop table #tbl
```

If memory serves me right, there an edge case that needs to be taken care of... log(0) is an error.

Comment: +1 for Smooth.  Too bad you'd have to wrap it to check for zeros and having to look at rounding/casting/overflow issues and potentially introducing precision errors in going to float.

Comment: great solution . I am very impressed.. this is the one i am looking for

Comment: note that for large sets this method will introduce rounding errors.
you might try the clr solution instead. it is slower but accurate.
i compared the 2 here:
http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/02/12/60088.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @result int
set @result = 1

select @result = @result * [number]
from tblNumber

print @result
```

(note that this assumes an int column and no overflow)

Comment: without declaring the @result, cannot we go for any other approach?

Like I don't want to take help of any variable. I am basically trying to get the solution using recursive CTE. But as of now no luck. I have to do it by using something like CTE/Corelated subquery etc.

Answer (score 0):

Michael's result is efficient.

You can use a recursive CTE, simply define a ROW_NUMBER and self-join.  But why bother, it won't be as efficient, since you need to do a table or index scan anyway.

Comment: i don't know if user can make user-defined aggregate in mssql, this is more efficient http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490875/why-the-result-of-exp-log-of-postgres-differs-from-sql-server