# Why the result of exp/log of Postgres differs from SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

I don't have SQL Server on my box, but why won't the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490433/performing-multiplication-in-sql-serverset-based-approach) return 360 on Postgres?

```
select exp(sum(log(val)))
from (values(4),(5),(3),(6)) as tbl(val)
```

returns 12.888075

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use natural logarithm (ln function), not base-10 logarithm (log function):

```
select exp(sum(ln(val)))
from (values(4),(5),(3),(6)) as tbl(val)

 exp 
-----
 360
(1 row)
```

But this is not a good way to multiply rows - it is slow and error prone due to rounding. You should declare an aggregate:

```
create function multiply(int,int) returns int as $$
  select $1*$2;
$$ language sql immutable strict;

create aggregate multiply(int) (
  sfunc=multiply,
  stype=int,
  initcond=1
);

select multiply(val)
from (values(4),(5),(3),(6)) as tbl(val)
 multiply 
----------
      360
(1 row)
```

Comment: :-) something for other rdbms users to envy about, i'll post your answer on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490433/performing-multiplication-in-sql-serverset-based-approach

Comment: :-) can you edit your question? so as to convince other rdbms users that postgresql is uber-flexible.  add this: 
select val, multiply(kyrie)
from (values(1,4),(8,5),(1,3),(8,6),(1,2)) as tbl(val, kyrie)
group by val 
order by val